# Es posible obtener el path de una carpeta con Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Estuve investigando bastante, pero nada prometedor, lo mas cercano que encontre era usar electron, cosa que reventaba el proyecto y la otra era intentar usar un input:

```
<input type="file" (change)="detectFiles($event)" #dropFile hidden directory webkitdirectory>
```

variante con electron:

```
browse() {
electron.remote.dialog.showOpenDialog({properties: ['openFile', 'openDirectory']}, (folderPath) => {
  if (folderPath === undefined){
    console.log("You didn't select a folder");
    return;
}
this.path = folderPath;
});}
```

El problema esta en que el de arriba es para subida masiva de archivos y pues no encontre nada en los console log, osea si acaso detecta que se clickeo.

```
selectFile(obj, event) {
event.stopPropagation();
this.object = obj;
console.log("obj =>", obj);
console.log("event =>", event);
this.nativeInputFile.nativeElement.click();}

detectFiles(event){
console.log("event =>", event);}
```

Casi siempre lei que no se podia, por un tema de seguridad en el navegador, se puede o no? ahi el dilema.

Answer (score 0):

Investigando al respecto, si no estoy mal, hace como 5 años se podia obtener la ruta completa real de un archivo directamente desde javascript y el input tipo file, pero esto generaba multiples problemas de seguridad, por este motivo se decidio que javascript no tendria acceso directo a funcionalidades de lectura y escritura de archivos, asi como de rutas, en definitiva, nada que tenga que ver con el fileSystem, nodejs permite acceso a fileSystem de manera nativa con el modulo fs, pero en resumen... da igual si usas nodejs para eso, porque si no tienes la ruta no tienes nada.

Y aunque se tuviese la ruta completa, node debe correr como servicio y en un servidor, o por lo menos eso es lo mas común, y las rutas que le pases a node no servirían entonces.

Por el lado de angular tenemos al plugin:

[cordova-plugin-file](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file)

Este plugin tiene cosas muy interesantes, una de ellas que me llamo bastante la atención es el metodo `resolveLocalFileSystemURL`, que ayuda a traducir rutas de muchos tipos a una la cual pueda manejar la plataforma en la que estas trabajando y así leer la información de este.

Este plugin lo uso actualmente en el desarrollo de una app móvil con ionic, es muy bueno y muy completo, pero desgraciadamente o quizás afortunadamente, tanto este plugin como otros que uso en la aplicación no te dan nunca la ruta real de un archivo, lo que hacen es copiar rapidamente el archivo a otra carpeta controlada por el plugin y te dan esa ruta y no la original.

Por otro lado existe un objeto interesante que no esta en los estandares de los navegadores, se llama `FileSystem`,no todos los navegadores implementan este objeto por lo que lo mas probable es que tengas problemas de compatibilidad con distintos navegadores si es que lo soportan.

Referencia a FileSystem y sus metodos propiedades e interfaces:

[FileSystem, metodos interfaces y propiedades](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_and_Directory_Entries_API)

El problema con fileSystem es que, pese a que permite leer y guardar información de manera nativa en javascript, no es estandar, puede tener problemas de compatibilidad y no te da las rutas originales tampoco, por ejemplo `FileSystemEntry.fullPath`, te da la ruta completa, pero del sandbox virtual donde se encuentra el archivo.

Es decir, para que nos entendamos, el metodo requestFileSystem(), nos pide el permiso para usar un espacio especial de nuestro almacenamiento en el disco duro definido por nosotros, ahora bien FileSystem según la documentación:

> FileSystem no garantiza acceso directo al sistema de archivos del
>   usuario. En vez de eso te provee de un disco virtual manejado por el
>   navegador (Sandbox).

En pocas palabras, tenemos el mismo problema, **no es la ruta real**, es una ruta de un disco virtual en el navegador.

Por ultimo tenemos exactamente lo que tu pusiste aquí:

```
<input type="file" directory webkitdirectory>
```

Poniendo el atributo directory y webkitdirectory nos permite que el navegador decida cual debe usar si es compatible con alguno de ellos, esto nos da cierta información un poco util, pero no la ruta completa del archivo... eso sí, la ruta es mucho mas completa que solo el nombre del archivo que nos provee por defecto el objeto **File** en este caso la podemos extraer cuando se hace un onchange del input tipo file:

```
detectFiles(event){
    console.log(event.currentTarget.files[0].webkitRelativePath);
}
```

Pero el mismo problema, **no es la ruta completa**, de todas maneras es algo mucho mas completo que simplemente el nombre del archivo que provee el tipo `File`.

Por lo que concluyendo un poco el tema, lo mas cercano y posible por ahora es simplemente conformarse con la ruta que usa `webkitRelativePath`, ya que por el momento no existe forma alguna de obtener la **ruta completa original** de una carpeta mediante **javascript nativo**, **angular**, **cordova** o **nodejs**, aclaro que digo que con nodejs no por que como dije anteriormente node deberia correr en un servidor, un servidor que no tiene acceso directamente a nuestros archivos locales de manera remota.

Sin embargo, si lo que quieres por ejemplo es usar archivos de una carpeta para leerlos como data, te puedo dar algunas cosas nativas utiles del navegador que lo permiten sin tener que usar rutas de archivos y esto mediante un input de tipo file, tenemos entonces dos importantes:

- **FileReader**: permite leer archivos de diferentes maneras pasandole como parametro principal un objeto `File`, puede leer la data del archivo ya sea como un string binario (actualmente depreciado), como texto (vigente), como url (base64, vigente) y como ArrayBuffer (vigente).

**IMPORTANTE:** todos los metodos de **FileReader** son asincronos por lo que se debería usar una **Promise** para recolectar la información de fileReader, o bien, hacer una función asincrona que te retorne la data ya cargada de algún metodo usado en **FileReader**.

- **URL.createObjectURL**: este metodo es sincrono y es instantaneo, lo que hace es crear una corta url a manera de 'referencia' al archivo y retorna la url unica, siempre la url será en formato blob y se debería usar el metodo **URL.revokeObjectURL** una vez se deje de usar la url de este recurso, de todas maneras el navegador destruye todos los objetos creados por URL.createObjectURL apenas se determine que el recurso no esta siendo usado o que la pagina haya sido descargada (unload o recarga de pagina) lo primero solo sucede en firefox de manera automatica, para chrome no sucede, por lo que tiene logica usarlo.

Referencias al objeto `FileReader`, `URL.createObjectURL` y `URL.revokeObjectURL`:

[FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/FileReader)

[URL.createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL)

[URL.revokeObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/URL/revokeObjectURL)

Conclusión, no se puede obtener la ruta real original del sistema de archivos por medio de javascript, angular, cordova, o nodejs **de la forma en la que lo necesitas.**, pero si se pueden obtener referencias a esa ruta o archivo y obtener sus datos en diferentes formatos.